# Travis-CI build failing with URL/hashed module dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package-managers, travis-ci

I have the following dependency array in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "doT": "git://github.com/nick-jonas/doT.git#cbc7041b646a79cca1034820db09167407d2f988",
    "lodash": "latest",
    "commander": "latest",
    "minimatch": "0.2.9",
    "prompt": "latest",
    "mkdirp": "latest",
    "fs-extra": ">=0.3.2",
    "shelljs": ">=0.1.0",
    "cheerio": ">=0.10.5",
    "readdirp": ">=0.2.1"
  }
```

Note the first dep:

`"doT": "git://github.com/nick-jonas/doT.git#cbc7041b646a79cca1034820db09167407d2f988"`

This *works* with npm.  When running `npm install` it will place the correct version of doT into my node_modules directory.  It will however give this error message when Travis-CI runs the test script:

```
227  vows test/*.js --spec
228
229
230  module.js:340
231    throw err;
232          ^
233  Error: Cannot find module 'doT'
234    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
235    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
236    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
237    at require (module.js:378:17)
238    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/builds/nick-jonas/assemblejs/lib/commands/writer.js:15:11)
239    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
240    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
241    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
242    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
243    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
244  npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
245  npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Running this command locally `vows test/*.js --spec` also works, so I'm assuming it's a problem with Travis-CI grabbing hashed-URL dependencies.

Anyone else have a problem similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a peek at your [TravisCI task that failed](https://travis-ci.org/nick-jonas/assemblejs/jobs/4115442), it seems like it did actually successfully install doT@1.0.0:

https://travis-ci.org/nick-jonas/assemblejs/jobs/4115442/#L188

If I [look at the dot.js project repository](https://github.com/olado/doT/blob/master/package.json#L2), it looks like the doT `package.json` file has the name listed as "dot" instead of "doT".

I'd try changing `require('doT')` to `require('dot')` in writer.js (or wherever else it's used).

It looks like this might be a case-sensitivity issue, which can be particularly annoying to deal with the npm world.

Answer (score 2):

@smithclay is exactly right. You are probably working on a Mac which has a case insensitive file system. Linux however, which travis is running on, does not.

I ran into a similar issue recently and created [valiquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/valiquire) to check that all require statements point to valid locations, including correct casing.

That way I can troubleshoot them locally. It also is useful to include a valiquire check as part of your tests in order to avoid breaking the build.